# MySQL my.cnf -- open-files-limit causing CPU Overload

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I got this server **Intel Xeon Quadcore E3-1230v2 with 8GBs of DDR3 RAM** Round the clock I see that this server is running out of CPU. It looks badly overloaded. After observing "*Daily Process Log*" I realized that below process is eating 25% of the CPU resources & there were three such processes (technically errors). Below is the process (error):

> /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir/ --datadir/var/lib/mysql --usermysql --log-error/var/lib/mysql/server.yacart.com.err --**open-files-limit16384** --pid-file/var/lib/mysql/server.yacart.com.pid

As visible in the above error, It appears something is wrong with **open-files-limit16384**, I tried increasing open-files-limit in my.cnf to 16384 but in vain. Below is how my my.cnf now looks like:

```
[mysqld]  
innodb_file_per_table=1  
local-infile=0  
open_files_limit=9978
```

Can anyone advise me a good configuration for my my.cnf ? Which would help me get rid of CPU overload?

There is a GoogleBot like robot script I am running in slave servers to mine data from internet. Its crawling the entire internet. When I shutdown this script, everything gets in order. I wonder if there is a fix I could apply to this script?

This robot program has got about 40 databases, each with a size of 50 - 800 MBs, total DB size of about 14 GBs so far & I expect this to shoot upto 500 GBs in future. At one point (whole day long) only ONE DB is used. Next day, I use next DB & so on. I was thinking of increasing RAM once the biggest DB reaches 2 GBs. Currently RAM does not seem to be an issue at all.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer.

regards,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

If you have WHM, look for this under **Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings >> SQL**

** Let cPanel determine the best value for your MySQL open_files_limit configuration ? [?]

cPanel will adjust the open_files_limit value during each MySQL restart depending on your total number of tables.

Comment: Good answer but for me it was already enabled in WHM and I am thinking that could be the prob but I cant find the field for the manual alternative.